# Reinterpreting improper integrals that require Cauchy principal value to be defined

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, philosophy

This question concerns the [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).  Consider the improper integral $$\int_{-∞}^{∞}\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}dx$$ which is divergent, and then its Cauchy principal value  $$\lim_{u \to ∞} \int_{-u}^{u}\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}dx=\pi$$ As I have yet to study [Lebesgue integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integral), but I was wondering whether it resolves problems of this nature - or if any other interpretation of the integral does. Just to clarify, by resolving I mean that the value of the integral does not have to be assigned to integrals that would otherwise be undefined.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "resolving problems of this nature." What problem of what nature, and what does it mean to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by resolving I mean that the value of the integral does not have to be assigned to integrals that would otherwise be undefined.

Well, you do not **have to** assign values to divergent integrals. Mathematicians use the Cauchy principal value when they **want to** use an integral which unfortunately happens to diverge. For example, consider the Poisson formula that gives the values of a harmonic function $u$ in the upper half-plane $H=\{(x,y):x\in\mathbb R,y>0\}$ in terms of its boundary values $u^*$: 
$$u(x,y)=\frac{y}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u^*(x-t)}{t^2+y^2}\,dt \tag1$$
When a function with boundary values $u^*(x)=1+x$ comes along, we have two ways to react:

1. "Formula (1) does not apply because the integral diverges"
2. "Formula (1) can be used if the integral is understood as Cauchy principal value"

I believe the second approach is more *constructive*™ and therefore is in the interest of the mathematical community. It yields
$$\lim_{A\to+\infty}\frac{y}{\pi}\int_{-A}^A \frac{1+x-t}{t^2+y^2}\,dt =\lim_{A\to+\infty} \frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(A/y)(1+x) = 1+x \tag2$$
which, while not very exciting, is a correct formula for a harmonic function with the given boundary values.

---

Does the Lebesgue theory of integration help us work with formulas such as (1)? Short answer: not at all. The Lebesgue theory is agnostic of the order structure of the domain of integration: it takes it as a whole, not as a sequence of expanding intervals. The concept of  Cauchy principal value is alien to it. The Lebesgue integral has many wonderful features (most importantly, powerful convergence theorems and the completeness of $L^p$ spaces) but it is not a flexible tool for dealing with divergent improper integrals. For example, the (conditionally) convergent integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ is deemed divergent by the Lebesgue theory.

Of course, one can take the Lebesgue integral over $[-A,A]$ and then let $A\to\infty$ with the same result as above. But the resulting notion of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ is closer in spirit to the Riemann integral; it depends on the order structure of the line and is not  as stable under convergence of integrands as integrals of $L^1$ functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure sure whether Lebesgue integration helps to *solve* that integral, though I think it doesn't. Perhaps a little complex analysis?

$$f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1+z^2}=\frac{1+z}{(z+i)(z-i)}$$

and we can take the contour determined by

$$C_R:=[-R,R]\cup\gamma_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=R\;,\;\text{Im}(z)\ge 0\}\;,\;\;R>>0$$

Within the domain bounded by the above curve we've only one simple pole, so

$$Res_{z=i}(f)=\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\frac{1+i}{2i}$$

so by Cauchy's Residue Theorem

$$2\pi i\cdot\frac{1+i}{2i}=\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)dz+\int_{-R}^R\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}dx$$

and passing to the limit when $\,R\to\infty\,$ and taking the real parts we get

$$\pi=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}dx$$

getting btw that the imaginary part has also the same value...

It should be noted that the imaginary part is due entirely to the loop integral; the imaginary part of the integral along the real axis is zero, as expected.